# How to access browser's "window" object in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, locker-service, static-resources

I have third party JS file that I have imported in Salesforce as Static Resource
Structure of static resource:

```
myuploadzip.zip
----myuploadzip.JS
```

I have imported the same in Aura Application as below:

```
ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myuploadzip}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}"  beforeLoadingResources="{!c.beforeLoad}"/>
```

**This JS is creating property in browser "window" object as `window.ABC`. I need to access that property in Aura Controller.js which I am unable to do.**
**Is there any way to access the same** ? I tried below code but unable to access in Aura controlelr.JS

```
var commAPI=window.ABC;
    var bridge = new commAPI.API('host'); 
    bridge.subscribe((message) => {
        //helper.handleIncomingEvent(message);
        console.log('Incoming event-->'+json.stringify(message));
    });
```

Note:
The above code is working when used with VF pages, assuming this must be the inaccessible due to LockerService.

Comment: I think this external JS library is not locker service compatible. You can check it by changing the API version of the component bundle to version 39.0. If this library will work - the problem is with lockerservice.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi - I chked with v39.0 , and the window object is accessible and value of window.ABC can be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component gets its own virtual window object (called a `SecureWindow`). If the script is attaching to `window.ABC`, it should be accessible as just `ABC` or `window.ABC`. Make sure you're not attempting to access it before `afterLoad` is called.

However, please note that if this code uses a Worker (typically a ServiceWorker), it will not work in Locker Service, as Workers are not supported in Locker Service. They are also inherently blocked in Lightning Experience and Communities even if you use v39.0 as your API version.

If you need inter-component support, use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel).